# Python using wrong encoding

Tags: python, character-encoding, python-3.x

Using python 3.2, I am trying to decode bytes using str(bytes, "cp1251") but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\---\---\---\---.py", line 4, in <module>
    writetemp.write(str(f.read(), "cp1251"))
  File "C:\Python32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 19-25: character     maps to <undefined>
```

As you can see, I specified "cp1251", but it attempts to use "cp1252.py" to decode instead of "cp1251.py", which causes the error, I think. Same thing occurs if I try "Windows-1251" instead of "cp1251".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note how what you're getting is a `UnicodeEncodeError`, *not* a `UnicodeDecodeError`. The error doesn't come from your `str(f.read(), "cp1251")` call. Instead, it comes from the `writetemp.write()` call.

The `str()` call decodes the bytes you get from `f.read()` using `cp1251` as the encoding. That works. That gives you a string (which is unicode, in Python 3.) `writetemp.write()` then has to turn the string back into bytes, by encoding it. It does that using the encoding you passed when opening `writetemp`, or the default IO encoding (which Python tries to guess at based on various things.) You can see which encoding that is by looking at the `encoding` attribute of the file object. You'll probably find it is `cp1252`. If you want to write in a particular encoding, don't rely on Python guessing at it; explicitly specify the encoding when you open the file.